# Change Value in Xml based on node

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a Xml and looking to replace few value using PowerShell, however I don't find a way to do it.

XML. I would like to replace value for username and password

```xml
<module-option name="userName" value="detest"/>
<module-option name="password" value="sss"/>
```

Example of the Xml:

```xml
<server>
  <subsystem>
    <security-domains>
      <security-domain>
        <authentication>
          <login-module code="ox" flag="required">
            <module-option name="userName" value="detest"/>
            <module-option name="password" value="sss"/>
         </login-module>
        </authentication>
      </security-domain>
    </security-domains>
  </subsystem>
</server>
```

Comment: Please show us a better (valid) example of the xml. Make sure we can see the whole structure. Now, we cannot see if there are more `</security-domain>` nodes, what the root element is etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`SelectSingleNode` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=net-7.0) to find and update those nodes, for example, this would work with the Xml presented in your question:

```bash
($xml = [xml]::new()).Load('path\to\source.xml')
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//module-option[@name='userName']")
$node.Value = 'newUser'
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//module-option[@name='password']")
$node.value = 'newPassword'
$xml.Save('path\to\destionation.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath to grab the relevant child nodes under the `<login-module code="ox">` node:

```
$newUsername = 'username123'
$newPassword = 'Sup3rS3cr3t'
$xmlDoc = [xml](Get-Content path\to\file.xml)

$usernameNode = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//security-domain/authentication/login-module[@code="ox"]/module-option[@name="userName"]') 
$usernameNode.SetAttribute('value', $newUserName)

$passwordNode = $xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//security-domain/authentication/login-module[@code="ox"]/module-option[@name="password"]') 
$passwordNode.SetAttribute('value', $newPassword)

$xmlDoc.Save((Resolve-Path path\to\output.xml))
```